# best mysql table type for thousands of tables in one db

Tags: mysql, optimization

I need to make a mysql database with thousands of tables. Is there an advantage to one table type over another for this single factor?

The reason for this is that each user will be inserting 100s of thousands of rows. So would like to give each one a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Without any other information in your question, I can only guess about how you are going to use these thousands of tables. Your intended usage probably has a lot to do with the choice of table type.

That said, one common problem that affects people who create thousands of small tables with MySQL is that each individual file is created with a default size on disk Suppose you only store a tiny amount of data in these tables, far less than the physical file size. That means you'll waste a lot of disk space.

For that reason, using InnoDB with `innodb_file_per_table` *disabled* can be more efficient regarding disk space, because all the tables will be combined into one physical tablespace file.

Again, that's just one aspect of table usage. Without providing more information, you can't get a full answer about tradeoffs.

---

Re your additional information:

MySQL can scale to hundreds of millions of rows. Just inserting hundreds of thousands of rows per user doesn't mean you need to split the table.

You may also define a table with [PARTITIONING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html) by user-id (which will create multiple physical tables but allow you to address the whole table as one if you need to).

Comment: thansk bill. i added some info.